# Bosis when the Davar Hater was left there accidentally

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh

If one intentionally left a rock on a table and accidentally left a bag of chips on the table as well, would the table be Mutar to move?

If he forgot the rock on the table obviously it would be Mutar to move the table. If he intentionally left both the rock and the bag of chips on the table, obviously it would be mutar to move the table as well. However, I have never seen discussed what the Halacha would be if one accidentally left the bag of chips on the table but intentionally left the rock there.

If anyone could provide some Mareh Mekomos that address this directly, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your examples for these cases are not the best. I suppose you choose a rock meaning something worthless and muktse. Then the 'forgot the rock' , a better example would be something worth more than the chips which would have the same din. I dont know the answer but I think your thoughts on the heter dont matter.